# Custom Styling Qt Quick Controls

Tags: qt, qml

I would like to have a custom design for my Qt Quick Controls. For example, I would like to change background colour of a tool bar, since I hate the default design. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Qt Quick Controls, there is [limited styling available](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtquickcontrolsstyles/qtquickcontrolsstyles-index.html) via Qt Quick Control Styles items, like `ButtonStyle`, `CheckBoxStyle`, etc.

At the moment, other styles require delving into [Qt sources](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtquickcontrols/source/c304d741a27b5822a35d1fb83f8f5e65719907ce:src/styles) and messing with internal details.

Here is a complete example of how one might modify the toolbar's style.

[image: screenshot]

`main.qml`

```
import QtQuick 2.1
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    toolBar: ToolBar {
        id: toolbar
        Component.onCompleted: toolbar.data[0].item.children = [newRectangle];
        property Item _newRectangle: Rectangle {
            // The rectangle within the ToolBarStyle's panel
            // Gleaned from:
            // http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtquickcontrols/source/
            //   c304d741a27b5822a35d1fb83f8f5e65719907ce:src/styles/Base/ToolBarStyle.qml
            id: newRectangle
            anchors.fill: parent
            gradient: Gradient{
                GradientStop{color: "#a00" ; position: 0}
                GradientStop{color: "#aaa" ; position: 1}
            }
            Rectangle {
                anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                width: parent.width
                height: 1
                color: "#999"
            }
        }
        RowLayout {
            ToolButton { iconSource: "image://images/img1" }
            ToolButton { iconSource: "image://images/img2" }
        }
    }
}
```

`main.cpp`

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQuickWindow>
#include <QImage>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QQuickImageProvider>
#include <QDebug>

class ImageProvider : public QQuickImageProvider
{
public:
    ImageProvider() : QQuickImageProvider(QQuickImageProvider::Image) {}
    QImage requestImage(const QString &id, QSize *size, const QSize &requestedSize) {
        QImage img(32, 32, QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);
        img.fill(0); // transparent
        QPainter p(&img);
        p.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
        p.translate(16, 16);
        p.scale(14, 14);
        p.setPen(QPen(Qt::black, 0.1));
        if (id == "img1") {
            p.drawEllipse(QPointF(0, 0), 1, 1);
        }
        else if (id == "img2") {
            p.drawLine(-1, -1, 1, 1);
            p.drawLine(-1, 1, 1, -1);
        }
        *size = img.size();
        return img;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.addImageProvider("images", new ImageProvider);
    engine.load(QUrl("qrc:///main.qml"));
    QObject *topLevel = engine.rootObjects().value(0);
    QQuickWindow *window = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow *>(topLevel);
    window->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

`main.qrc`

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>main.qml</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the following lines are completely useless:

```
QObject *topLevel = engine.rootObjects().value(0);
QQuickWindow *window = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow *>(topLevel);
window->show();
```

You just need to do something like:

```
QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
return app.exec();
```

Comment: Oh man, this was 2 years ago. Thanks for taking your time though. :)